# Pass json object from module to index.vue file in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to fetch a json file from amazon s3 using aws-sdk by creating a module. The fetched json must be passed to the index page (index.vue).

Fetching the data is working, but i can't figure out the way to pass the json from module to the page